# Exception: Access denied: DriveApp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I made a script that receive a list of emails of users that need to be removed from accessing a given Google drive folder. Here is the snippet with the function that removes a user:

```
 function remove_user(drive_folder,user_email){

   if(drive_folder.getAccess(user_email) != "NONE"){
     Logger.log("removing user: " + user_email);
     drive_folder.revokePermissions(user_email);
   }

 }
```

An exception is raised when the revokePermission method is called:

> Exception: Access denied: DriveApp

Thing is, the script did ask the first time for a DriveApp permission to my email account and i gave it(Other DriveApp methods work pretty fine in the same script). Also, my email account has the permission to remove users from the google drive folder i'm targeting(I can manually remove users using my google account).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: How do you run the function `remove_user`? Can you provide the detail flow for correctly replicating your issue?

Comment: This is clearly an Google Drive bug, please file an issue at http://issuetracker.google.com/ for fellow Google developers be aware of it and may fix it as you log it in their beautiful public issue tracker website

Comment: Oh wait, it's already fixed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761393 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118423385 what a nice example of bugs fixing from Google!

Answer (score 0):

1. The user you are logging in with needs to be owner of the file to remove others permissions.
2. If this is a workspace account make sure the DriveApp is activated in the Admin Console for you or your domain.

Answer (score 0):

By design, you cannot remove the owner of the shared folder. If you try to do it as an editor, your exception will arise. If you try to remove yourself (being the owner) an `Exception: Invalid argument: file.owner` will arise.

This is how it is designed to work. A folder (or a file for that matter) always has an owner, regardless of how it is shared. You can read more about how permissions in Google Drive work [here](https://apps.google.com/supportwidget/articlehome?hl=en&article_url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupport.google.com%2Fa%2Fanswer%2F7662202%3Fhl%3Den&product_context=7662202&product_name=UnuFlow&trigger_context=a).

Naturally, using AppsScript you can remove other editors of the folder via `DriveApp.revokePermissions()` as you would do it manually.